# jquery get real table height when tbody has lot of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `<table>` element with a lot of rows and a `max-height` attribute.
I need to find the real height displayed for the `<tbody>` element. Normally I can just take the difference between `<table>` height and `<thead>` height

```
var tbodyDispalyHeight = $("table").height() - $("thead").height();
```

This works unless horizontal content is too much and an horizontal scrollbar appears (and can't remove it because... I need it!). I should remove its height from `tbodyDispalyHeight` but... how can I do?
First problem: I don't really know when this bar is displayed
Second prolbem: Each browser implement scrollbar in a different way

Here is a [JSBIN example](http://output.jsbin.com/zirovibuku) to understand what I mean. Try to resize page horizontally until the scrollbar appears, there the `dislayed tbody height` should be lower...

Comment: Could always count table elements and times that by pre-defined element height :) *$('table').find('element').length* then times by *21px* in the case of each TD element being 21px.

Comment: @JordanLowe that way I get the size of `<tbody>`, not the pixels used to display `<tbody>` that are much lesser and don't depend on single row height

Comment: What ist about `$("table")[0].clientHeight`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for the clientHeight.
(But this seems to be to easy.)
Have a look to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight)
*The Element.clientHeight read-only property is zero for elements with no CSS or inline layout boxes, otherwise it's  the inner height of an element in pixels, including padding but not the horizontal scrollbar height, border, or margin.*
You may try:

```
$("table")[0].clientHeight
```

Comment: Thank you, you pointed me in the right direction. To find the scrollbar height i just take the difference between an element `offsetHeight` and its `clientHeight`. An example is `var barHeight = $("#offerTable")[0].offsetHeight - $("#offerTable")[0].clientHeight`

Answer (score 1):

Currently you have your table with overflow:auto. But you could wrap it with a DIV with "overflow:auto". Then you can simply determine if you have a horizontal scrollbar by comparing the width of your div with the width of your table.

Comment: Seems a good solution, thank you for the hint. I used the above one because it doesn't require any "fake" element addition but this is fine too :)